# Unclear passage in Lorentz generators derivation

Tags: special-relativity, field-theory, tensor-calculus, group-theory

It's not clear to me a passage, in the extraction of the generators of Lorentz's group acting on the Minkowksi's space points: we have

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
x^{' \alpha} & = \Lambda^{\alpha}_{\beta} x^{\beta} \\\\
& = (\delta^{\alpha}_{\beta} + \omega^{\alpha}_{\beta}) x^{\beta} \\\\
& = (\delta^{\alpha}_{\beta} + \omega^{\mu\nu} \delta^{\alpha}_{\mu}\eta_{\nu\beta}) x^{\beta} \\\\
& = \left[\delta^{\alpha}_{\beta} + \frac{1}{2} \omega^{\mu\nu} (\delta^{\alpha}_{\mu} \eta_{\nu\beta} - \delta^{\alpha}_{\nu} \eta_{\mu\beta})\right] x^{\beta} \\\\
& = \left[\delta^{\alpha}_{\beta} - \frac{i}{2} \omega^{\mu\nu} (M_{\mu\nu})^{\alpha}_{\beta} \right] x^{\beta}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Why do we have to write $(M_{\mu\nu})^{\alpha}_{\beta}$ as $(\delta^{\alpha}_{\mu} \eta_{\nu\beta} - \delta^{\alpha}_{\nu} \eta_{\mu\beta})$?

Weren't we just fine with $(M_{\mu\nu})^{\alpha}_{\beta} = \delta^{\alpha}_{\mu} \eta_{\nu \beta}$?

I don't get why we need to write $M$ with such a trick

Comment: the $\omega$ are antisymmetric, so you need to have $M_{\mu\nu} = -M_{\nu\mu}$. The correct formula is the antisymetrisation of yours.